# Существуют ли препроцессоры Fortran к СУБД?

Tags: fortran, linux

ОС Linux. Язык программирования Fortran 95.

Comment: Я склонен к тому, что нет, Фортран, тем более 95, мало функциональный. Он годен делать только

a=1

b=1

c=a+b

print*,c

Comment: Не вижу связи между препроцессорами и СУБД. Оу, вкурил. Имеется ввиду трасляция кода из fortran'а в SQL?

Comment: Для работы с базами есть другие языки. Функциональности в Фортране хватает. Пользоваться ей нужно уметь.

Comment: Вопрос!
Почему Фортран?

Comment: Видимо надо делать научные расчеты и есть исходники функций, а массивы данных в СУБД.

Comment: Вариант.Ответ понял

Answer (score 1):

Что-то безусловно можно найти. Например, [Fortran SQL preprocessor Oracle & Ot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/profor/). Насколько это качественно и работоспособно, сказать трудно.